# Problems with conversion from "nvarchar" to "date" MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following Select Statement which drives me crazy:

```
select
(Case when Buchungskreis in ('0001', '0002', '0003', '0004') then (Case when Kostenstelle is null then Buchungskreis else Buchungskreis + '.' + Kostenstelle end) else Buchungskreis end),
'SAP-USER Typ ' + Typ ,
1,
convert(date, '01.01.2014', 104),
SAPUser
from Z_SAP_USER
where Buchungskreis is not null
and flagmehrfachanmeldung = 0
and BIS not like '00.00.0000'
and convert(date,convert(varchar,bis),104)
between convert(date, '01.01.2014', 104)
and convert(date, '31.01.2014', 104)
```

Is says

```
Error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
SQLState:  22007
ErrorCode: 241
```

When I remove the last three lines, it works, so the troublemaker is within the last three lines.

```
BIS
```

is nvarchar and some lines contain the values `00.00.0000` which of course can#t be convertet do date format.

The following statement works:

```
select convert(date,convert(varchar,bis),104) from Z_SAP_USER
where BIS not like '00.00.0000'
```

which is exactly the same I use in my query....

I also tried this one without success:

```
select
(Case when s1.Buchungskreis in ('0001', '0002', '0003', '0004') then (Case when s1.Kostenstelle is null then s1.Buchungskreis else s1.Buchungskreis + '.' + s1.Kostenstelle end) else s1.Buchungskreis end),
'SAP-USER Typ ' + s1.Typ ,
1,
convert(date, '01.01.2014', 104),
s1.SAPUser
from Z_SAP_USER s1
inner join Z_SAP_USER s2 on (s1.sapuser=s2.sapuser and s2.bis not like '00.00.0000')
where s1.Buchungskreis is not null
and s1.flagmehrfachanmeldung = 0
and convert(date,convert(varchar,s1.bis),104)
between convert(date, '01.01.2014', 104)
and convert(date, '31.01.2014', 104)
```

Of course I tried cast instead of convert, but that also din't work...
Does anyone have an Idea whats wrong with my select??

Comment: is the value actually a date?  convert and cast wont work no matter what you do if the value is not a real date.

Comment: There's no short-circuiting or guaranteed evaluation order within SQL Server - just because you've written `WHERE A AND B` doesn't mean that the system won't attempt to evaluate `B` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that there is no short cutting of logical predicates in SQL WHERE clause. So even though you filtered out problematic rows by this

```
where BIS not like '00.00.0000'
```

It still tries to calculates this

```
and convert(date,convert(varchar,bis),104)
```

And this causing an error.
Try using `try_convert` function. It will return `NULL` for such rows but I think it won't break your logic.

```
and try_convert(date,convert(varchar,bis),104)
```

Comment: I was thinking about the short cutting thing...but had no idea to solve that...but that works!!!! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since as you mentioned it is the last three lines of your code is giving the problem,
you can try replacing '00.00.0000' by empty

```
and convert(date,convert(varchar,replace(s1.bis,'00.00.0000',''),104)
between convert(date, '01.01.2014', 104)
and convert(date, '31.01.2014', 104)
```

Comment: Should also work. But the other solution was faster. Anyway: Thanks too!